# Predicting next word using LSTM from Tensorflow1.12 tutorial in Feb 2019

Tags: python, tensorflow

How does LSTM next word prediction take in a string of words and output the next word? I am looking for a function that can take in the sentence and model, and output a word.

See tutorial here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py

I am using the same code, which you can see above.

Please don't mark this question as duplicate. I see similar questions have been asked with no accepted answer, and no recent questions that specifically apply to Tensorflow 1.12. I have spent days going through old comments, blog posts, and githubs claiming to have the answer.

Comment: so do you want to understand the code or the concept behind it?

Comment: @ Vaibhav gusain Both! I do think I have a pretty good understanding of the concept behind it from older questions I read. I think we need a index to word matrix and then we should be able to use the output word vector to look up the word in the index to word matrix. But I am not sure, and I'm not sure how to even create this index to word matrix because we end up passing the word vectors not the word itself to the LSTM.

Comment: yea usually when we deal with words we dont actually pass the strings we do some preprocessing on the word and then feed it to our neural network.
you can look at word2Vec repr for an example.